# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error:0

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, ssl, iis

I am getting the below exception while making the database call from an IIS deployed application Asp.Net Core 3.1 API.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL
> Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)

It workes as expected If I restart the application in IIS. But this error starts again in some days. So I need a permanent solution and root cause to this issue.

**ConnectionString:**

"Data Source=ABC.PQR.XYZ.IT.SQL;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=User;Password=***",

**Note:**

The same application is working as expected on different servers and pointing to a different database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some connectivity issues between my server machine and database server, I have solved the issue by adding `MultiSubnetFailover=True`to the connection string.

Answer (score 5):

With limited information provided, I am assuming that you are using `Data.SqlClient`. Try adding the following to the connection string.

```
"Data Source=ABC.PQR.GCXYZ.IT.SQL;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=User;Password=***;TrustServerCertificate=true",
```

Since it works for a few days with no issues, it might be due to the application occupying the allowable connection limits like a bad recursion that exponentiate the calls to the database.

Comment: Any reasons for this?

Comment: If your web server uses self signed certificates then you have to add this attribute to the connection string. If that is not the case, see if my second troubleshooting step works.

Comment: But how is it working on other server perfectly fine?

Comment: Do both the servers have the same authorized SSL certificates?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: In IIS, click on the server name and in the features pane select "server certificates". Select a certificate and click view.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, I could solve the issue by trying a different solution. but your suggestion taught me something which I didn't know before.